# Como acessar posição de retorno JSON com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Como faço para acessar alguma posição do array abaixo dependendo da escolha do usuário em um `select`? Por exemplo: se ele selecionar a opção 11 no `select` eu exibo o valor da chave `installmentAmount` da posição 11 para o usuário.

```
{error: false, installments: {…}}
    error:false
    installments:mastercard:Array(12)
    0:{quantity: 1, installmentAmount: 200.5, totalAmount: 200.5, interestFree: true}
    1:{quantity: 2, installmentAmount: 100.25, totalAmount: 200.5, interestFree: true}
    11:{quantity: 12, installmentAmount: 18.77, totalAmount: 225.18, interestFree: false}
    length:12
```

Comment: Consegui, acessei usando o seguinte: console.log(response.installments[bandeira][valor].installmentAmount)

Answer (score 2):

A forma de acesso de um objeto neste caso é equivalente a um array:

```
objeto[índice]
```

Neste seu exemplo:

```js
var obj = {error: false, installments: {},
    error:false,
    installments:'',
    0:{quantity: 1, installmentAmount: 200.5, totalAmount: 200.5, interestFree: true},
    1:{quantity: 2, installmentAmount: 100.25, totalAmount: 200.5, interestFree: true},
    11:{quantity: 12, installmentAmount: 18.77, totalAmount: 225.18, interestFree: false},
    length:12
}
  
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj[11]));
```